# PhpStorm doesn't find PHP Interpreter on POP OS

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am configuring my environment with PhpStorm 2022.2.1 and POP_OS 22.04, however when I set the PHP CLI Interpreter the system does not find the PHP interpreter (`/usr/bin/php` or `/bin/php`). The PhpStorm terminal /bin/bash is also unable to execute commands like `php -v`.

Has anyone had this problem ?

Directly in the terminal the interpreter works correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html

Comment: Are you sure that you even have PHP installed?

Comment: How did you install PhpStorm? Was it flatpack, from an archive or some another way?

Comment: Yes, the PHP is installed. It's work correctly when open a terminal. PHPStorm was installed with pop_shop and flatpak, however the problem is the same.

Comment: Install using the PHPStorm toolbox. I've had similar issues with the flatpak install and it got resolved when I used the Toolbox install

Comment: @UnderDog tks, my problem was resolved  when I installed by Jetbrains Tollbox

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem configuring my environment with PhpStorm-2022.2.3 and Fedora 36. I downloaded PHPStorm from Fedora Software Centre (Flatpak). The system did not find the PHP interpreter at `/usr/bin/php` or `/opt/lampp/php`. I uninstalled it and installed it from the JetBrains [website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installation-guide.html#standalone) directly using the standalone installer and it solved the issue.

[PHP interpreter PHPStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKCJ6.png)